# disable phpmailer error messages

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

When I send the mail I am getting the error messages on the screen, things like...

```
> Invalid address:  Invalid address:
> 423Invalid address: 423
```

How can I switch this off?

Thanks,

R.

Comment: Perhaps by validating the address before trying to send?

Comment: Do you want to disable it or avoid it (solve it)?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following setting.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->do_debug = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it commenting the line that have the echo that displays the error.

```
if (!self::ValidateAddress($address)) {
  $this->SetError($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '. $address);
  if ($this->exceptions) {
    throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '.$address);
  }
  //echo $this->Lang('invalid_address').': '.$address; <----- COMMENT THIS LINE (LINE 464)
  return false;
}
```

After this, even that the address is invalid, the message is not displayed.

by Tronks

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of information we have from the question I'm not sure the answer is correct but, when you put the `@` sign before the mail function.

```
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Suppreses the errors, but you h¡should hide errors for "sticking your head under the sand", this should be done to avoid ugly/unfriendly erros etc, you shouldn't hide from your errors.

Comment: what Trufa is suggesting is correct, but is not correct! And I am not bipolar. Is just that hidding errors is not a good thing. Try to fix them instead of hiding. Software developers throw errors for a reason.

Answer (score -2):

Throw errors is ok, but if you intend to catch the (error) result and map it into an own result (e.g. you want to create an json result) you'll get a problem with these html outputs.

Comment: You should be more explicit. Try explaining a little bit more and add examples.